# Navigate (with state) from react-router-dom v6 action

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

**actions/billAction.tsx**

```
import api from "../utils/api";

export default async function({ request }: { request: any }) {
  try {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const data : { [key: string]: string } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    let items : { [key: string]: { [key: string]: number } } = {};

    const clientName = data.clientName;

    for (const key in data) {
      const value = data[key];

      if (key !== "clientName" && value !== "") {
        const [type, id] = key.split("-");
        if (!items[id]) {
          items[id] = {};
        }
        items[id][type] = parseInt(value);
      }
    }

    const itemsArray = Object.entries(items).map(([key, value]) => ({
      _id: key,
      ...value
    }));

    const response = await api.post("/bill", { clientName: clientName, products: itemsArray });
    // where to call useNavigate() hook?
    // navigate("/bill/render", { state: { bill: response.data } });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

**components/BillRender.tsx**

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function(){
  const location = useLocation();
  const bill = location.state.bill;
  console.log(bill);

  useEffect(() => {
    const billDiv = document.getElementById("bill");
    if (billDiv) {
      billDiv.innerHTML = bill;
    }
  }, [bill]);

  return (
    <div id="bill">
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to load the state in component **BillRender.tsx**

The problem with,

- **Navigate** is that returning it from action would not result in it rendering
- **useNavigate** is that I cannot call it within the async **billAction.tsx** function

Here is the github [repo-link](https://github.com/sarvjot/invoice-generator-client/)

I would have used [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) if usecase was just to redirect without passing data.

Answer (score -1):

The [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect#redirect) utility is the correct function to use here, but you'll need to return a redirect response with the payload. The UI component uses the [`useActionData`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-action-data) hook to access the returned data.

```js
return redirect("...");
```

is shorthand for

```js
new Response("", {
  status: 302,
  headers: {
    Location: someUrl,
  },
});
```

The following should be close to what you are looking for.

```js
export default async function({ request }: { request: any }) {
  try {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const data: { [key: string]: string } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    let items: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: number } } = {};

    const clientName = data.clientName;

    for (const key in data) {
      const value = data[key];

      if (key !== "clientName" && value !== "") {
        const [type, id] = key.split("-");
        if (!items[id]) {
          items[id] = {};
        }
        items[id][type] = parseInt(value);
      }
    }

    const products = Object.entries(items).map(([key, value]) => ({
      _id: key,
      ...value
    }));

    const response = await api.post("/bill", { clientName, products });

    return new Response(response, { // * Note
      status: 302,
      headers: {
        Location: "/bill/render",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return error;
  }
}
```

****Note:** `response` may need to be re-JSON stringified to be returned as a response from the action function.*

In React we don't directly manipulate the DOM if we can help it. Just render `bill` as part of the normal JSX return in the UI component

```js
import { useActionData } from "react-router-dom";

export default function(){
  const actionData = useActionData();
  const bill = actionData?.data;

  if (!bill) {
    return /* fallback UI */;
  }

  return (
    <div id="bill">
      {bill}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I tried response and JSON.stringify(response), but actionData is undefined in both cases. Could it be the case that useActionData is not populated by this navigation because we are [not posting anything](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-action-data#useactiondata)?

Comment: @Sarvjot Possibly, we can't see how form submission is initiated in your code snippets. The `Form` component uses the GET method by default, which won't call any route actions. Ensure the `Form` component you are using specifies one of the mutation methods, e.g. POST, PUT, etc. See https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/form#mutation-submissions. It looks like you could also use the [useLoaderData](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-loader-data) hook with route action response values.